# SDC Constraint for reset synchronizer

Tags: fpga, vhdl, reset, timing-analysis, sdc

I have a reset bridge in VHDL which is based on a multi-FF synchronizer chain as depicted below. This reset bridge is used in various instances throughout my design.
I want to properly constrain the path to the asynchronous clear port.

[image: Reset synchronizer]

Constraint:

```
set_max_delay -to [get_pins -hierarchical *i_reset_bridge*|s_rst_sync_FF[*]|ACLR] 10.000
```

Quartus tells me that it cannot find any matching pins:

```
Argument <to> is an empty collection
```

Any hint on how to get my sdc running?

Comment: This will be FPGA and tool dependent.

Comment: Intel MAX 10, Quartus Prime 18.1

Comment: This reset bridge synchronises only the de-assertion of the async reset, the reset-assertion to your design is still asynchronous. Is your design using a global asynchronous reset? Just to confirm your intent.

Comment: @MituRaj I am aware of that and this is intended. Such reset bridges are recommended by various vendors like Xilinx or Altera/Intel. The global reset is generated via a locked signal from a clock primitive and synced to the global clock by a reset bridge. The synchronization to other clock domains is also realized via reset bridges in the corresponding modules.

Comment: I know. but if your design is expecting a synchronous reset inside, this reset bridge show on the figure is not enough. The assertion will still cause metastability. That is what I was saying.

Comment: @MituRaj Yes, assertion can cause metastability. But the reset pulse is stretched by the reset bridge to allow enough time for the metastability to settle.

Comment: I guess that's fine then. So here what you should be looking at is simply putting set max delay between the two flops. The meta-flop (first flop) is launching, the second flop is capturing. So that path has to be constrained to place the flops as close as possible.

Comment: Something like: set_max_delay -from [get_cells flopA] -to [get_cells flopB] 2 ; you will get the full hierarchial name of flopA and flopB from schematic/netlist.

Answer (score 3):

My constraints now look like this:

```
set_max_delay -to [get_pins -nocase -hierarchical s_rst_sync_ff[*]|CLRN] 10.000
set_max_delay -from [get_cells -nocase -hierarchical s_rst_sync_ff[*]] -to [get_cells -nocase -hierarchical s_rst_sync_ff[*]] 2.500
```

Besides, I enabled synchronizer identification in the Quartus qsf file:

```
set_global_assignment -name SYNCHRONIZER_IDENTIFICATION "FORCED IF ASYNCHRONOUS"
```

With these settings, the design meets timing and all synchronizer flops are placed close together.

Comment: The first statement is not actually needed on CLRN, as an asynchronous assertion doesn't need to be constrained on sdc, only de-assertion by the synchronizer has to be.                                                   
By the way, Is" s_rst_sync_ff"  the name of the synchronizer module instance? What's the need of -nocase/hierarchial? Just wondering.

Comment: @MituRaj The VHDL signal s_rst_sync_ff is a std_logic_vector based shift register. It's the synchronizer flop chain.

Comment: @MituRaj hierarchical is needed because I have multiple instances of the reset bridge in different module at different hierarchy levels in my design. nocase could be omitted I guess.

Comment: Cheers mate ...

Comment: @MituRaj thx a lot!